# Apex how to loop through returned records and pick the one that has a checkbox checked

Tags: apex, visualforce, wrapper-class

I am trying to look through a list of records returned after I perform a search. Within my custom VF controller, I have another class/wrapper, where I am getting all of the fields. Is it possible to loop though my class and identify the records that were selected?

```
public Class MergedSearchResult{
        public Boolean isSelected {get;set;}
        public String companyName {get;set;}    
        public String masterId  {get;set;}
        public String constType {get;set;}
        public String request_transaction_key {get;set;}
        public String email {get;set;}
        public String phone {get;set;}
        public String addr_line_1 {get;set;}
        public String addr_line_2 {get;set;}
        public String city {get;set;}
        public String state {get;set;}
        public String zip {get;set;}
        public String address {get;set;}
        public list<Account> Accounts {get;set;} 
        public String deceased {get;set;}
        public String Status {get;set;}

    }


        for(MergedSearchResult result : recordsList){
            if(result.isSelected == true){
                selectedRecords.add(result);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Ivo, it looks like you've already written code here that aligns with your requirement. Could you [edit] your question to be specific about what assistance you need from the community?

Comment: Why don't you sort through your selected records prior to creating the MergedSearchResultClass?  I think there are many more parts to do what you want to achieve than what you are displaying here.  If you want to do logic with the wrapper class to do some initialization, you will need to do a constructor method  `public MergedSearchResult()`  that does some logic with parameters that you pass into it.